# passing converted javascript array from php to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to pass javascript array(converted from php to js) present in php code to javascript function.

```
<?php

//php to javascript array conversion
$php_array = array('he','hi','hello');
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo 'var groups = ". $js_array . ";\n';

?>

function codeAddress(groups)
{ alert("into code address function");

        for (var i=0;i<groups.length;i++)
    {
        alert(groups[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code? What does it do, and what do you expect it to do instead? You can't expect to be able to just dump code here without explaining what exactly is wrong.

Comment: The syntax highlighting in the question shows what the issue is. You've mixed two types of quotes, `"` and `'`. So you're not actually setting your js variable to what you expect.

Comment: yes, adding " quote worked! but i am unable to call the codeAddress(groups) function from php. :(

Comment: Which is the correct behaviour - PHP is server-side, JS is client-side - the two can't really interact like that.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 'var groups = '. $js_array . ";\n";
```

Variable was not expanded inside single quotes. Don't put output of json_encode into quotes.

Comment: yes, adding " quote worked! but i am unable to call the codeAddress(groups) function from php. :(

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, its output is send to the browser, javascript is then executed in the browser. Just add `codeAddress(groups);` after defining the javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
    //php to javascript array conversion
    $php_array = array('he','hi','hello');
    $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
    echo 'var groups = '. $js_array;
```